# Olney Font for Dygraphs on Mobile

Tags: css, xamarin, fonts, dygraphs

I am using the dygraphs javascript library in a mobile app. I have embedded the Olney font into my mobile app and am using it find.

I am using Xamarin with the built in browser to display my graphs.

I would like to use that Olney font in the graph.

I was able to affect the y axis font by using CSS in the style:

```
.dygraph-axis-label {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

This set it to Arial just fine. When I try to use Olney it goes to regular Serif times new roman type font.

Can someone tell me how to get the Olney font to work?

Comment: Is the font loaded in to the built in browser for use by dygraphs?

Comment: That is what I am asking how to do. Sorry I was not clear on that. Can you tell me how to do that?